# Is there a way to manage external links in Sitecore Content Editor so that it can be reused?

Tags: content-editor

Recently I got an interesting query from one our Sitecore clients. The current site they are working on has a large number of external links. If they use the hyper link manager to add these links maintaining / changing these links will be very difficult since the content editor has to go through 100s of pages to do the update. Is there a way to reuse the links or have a dictionary of links to be used by content editors?

Any module/tip or trick to achieve this kind of requirement?

Comment: where do you have external links ? on  a richtext field or an external link?

Comment: Please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337280/extending-internal-link-and-external-link-to-allow-selection-of-images

Comment: @VladIobagiu - It's in RTE. I think it needs some customization with HyperLink Manager to allow linking existing item where content editor can create custom item (e.g Dictionary kind of) to store all external links. Content author can then select that item to link external url.

Comment: I am also looking for this feature to maintain external links in master location and refer.
Unfortunately, I could not find any thing .. Please let me know if it is possible similar to Image library.